# How to clear setInterval ID in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, setinterval

I am building a basic timer in Angular. For this I have two button, one of them starts the timer and the other stops it. I am implementing setInterval with 1000ms delay. But when I press the stop button, the timer stops but the timeoutId is not cleared. I want to prevent the user not to start another timer when the first one doesnt finish. I use - if (this.timeoutId) return; - But I am not able to start it again as I stop it.
The question is how I can prevent the user to start new timer when the timer started. And how can I start it again when I stop it.

//game-control-component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-game-control',
  templateUrl: './game-control.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./game-control.component.css'],
})
export class GameControlComponent implements OnInit {

@Output() onIncrement: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter();
timer: number = 0;
timeoutId!: ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>;

constructor() {
  console.log(this.timeoutId);
}

increment() {
  this.timer++;
}

startTimer() {
  if (this.timeoutId) return;
  this.timeoutId = setInterval(() => {
    this.increment();
    this.onIncrement.emit(this.timer);
  }, 1000);
}

stopTimer() {
  clearInterval(this.timeoutId);
  console.log(this.timeoutId);
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  console.log(this.timeoutId);
 }

}
```

//game-control-component-html

```
<div class="row mt-5">
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="button-group d-flex justify-content-evenly">
      <button (click)="startTimer()" class="btn btn-primary">Start</button>
      <button (click)="stopTimer()" class="btn btn-danger">Stop</button>
    </div>
  <h1 class="mt-5" style="text-align: center">{{ timer }}</h1>
  </div>
```

Comment: What about `this.timeoutId = null`?

Comment: Are You allowed or can You use RxJs, if Yes I can show another alternative solution using RxJs to create a simple timer.

Comment: this.timeoutId = null; I get error. I cannot assign Timeout type to null. I think it comes from typescript. "Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Timeout'. I dont know RxJs yet.

Answer (score 2):

There is no inbuilt way for achieving this.

The only possible solution is to clear the interval variable once you clear the interval object.

```
stopTimer() {
  clearInterval(this.timeoutId);
  this.timeoutId = null; // Clear the timeoutId
}
```

And now the start timer works as expexted. You are checking whether the timeoutId exist inside the start timer function

```
startTimer() {
  if (this.timeoutId) return; // Function will exist from here if timeoutId exist
  this.timeoutId = setInterval(() => {
    this.increment();
    this.onIncrement.emit(this.timer);
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: I have tried it but I got at line this.timeoutId = null;  "Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Timeout'". Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: I have solved it when I use the any type for timeoutId. `timeoutId!: any;` But I am not sure whether it is a good practice

Comment: In Node.js, you might encounter the "Type 'Timer' is not assignable to type 'number'" error. This is because in Node.js setInterval() returns a Timer object instead of a numeric id. To work around this, you can either specify Timer as the return type, infer the return type, or use window.setInterval() instead of setInterval() (which will return a numeric id as expected).  https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/what-is-the-correct-typescript-return-type-for-javascripts-setinterval-function#:~:text=js%20setInterval()%20returns%20a,you%20found%20this%20post%20useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // clear the timer once you click the stop button set 0 the timer variable .
stopTimer() {
      clearInterval(this.timeoutId);
      this.timer= 0; // Clear the timer
    }
    startTimer() {
      if (this.timeoutId) return; // remove this one
      this.timeoutId = setInterval(() => {
        this.increment();
        this.onIncrement.emit(this.timer);
      }, 1000);
    }
```

Comment: I dont want to clear timer. Did you mean timeoutId?